# Using useContext in React doesn't give me the expect data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I've been following some React Hooks tutorials to use `useContext`.

In a parent component, I created a new context,

`export const Context = createContext({fakeData: 'fake'})`

Then in one of the child components, I tried to access this data by doing,

```
 console.log('fakeData1', useContext(Context))
 const context = useContext(Context)
 console.log('fakeData2', context)
```

then I imported `Context` from the parent component.

Within my `console.log`, the `fakeData2` gives me undefined, but the `fakeData1` gives me

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.context), _calculateChangedBits: null, _currentValue: undefined, _currentValue2: {…}, _threadCount: 0, …}
$$typeof: Symbol(react.context)
Consumer: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.context), _context: {…}, _calculateChangedBits: null, …}
Provider:
$$typeof: Symbol(react.provider)
_context: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.context), _calculateChangedBits: null, _currentValue: {…}, _currentValue2: {…}, _threadCount: 0, …}
__proto__: Object
_calculateChangedBits: null
_currentRenderer: {}
_currentRenderer2: null
_currentValue: {fakeData: "fake"}
_currentValue2: {fakeData: "fake"}
_threadCount: 0
__proto__: Object
```

Since it has the data in the `Context`, I assume the import was successful, but I am not sure why I cannot access it directly through

```
const context = useContext(Context)
console.log('fakeData2', context)
```

I was assuming this object to have a field called `fakeData`, but it doesn't.

Any help?

Comment: Does `const {fakeData} = useContext(Context)` give you what you're looking for?

Comment: That's what I expected, but it doesn't. The `Context` object doesn't have the field called `fakeData`

Comment: I've noticed a weird behavior where setting the default value in `createContext` directly leads to undefined behavior. Try initializing it in the `value` property of the provider and leave the parameters to `createContext` blank

Comment: Are you saying empty the parameter of the `Context` like `export const Context = createContext()`? This also didn't work. It gives me the same result

Comment: Check out this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-wilbur-xebl0?file=/src/App.js) it shows a working example. But if you remove the `value` property from the `Context.Provider` component and instead place the default value inside the call to `createContext` it leads to the undefined behavior you were describing

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work somehow. It seems like I cannot directly access the `fakeData` through the object, but it works when I initialize it. I still don't fully understand the behavior but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. Should I post my answer then?

Comment: Sure. Go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the default values you want in context through the `value` property of the context's provider instead of passing them into `createContext`.

Here's what I mean:

```
// context.js
import { createContext } from "react";

export const Context = createContext(); // leave empty

// app.js
import React from "react";

import { Context } from "./context";

import Child from "./Child";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ fakeData: "test" }}> {/* pass default here */}
      <div className="App">
        <Child />
      </div>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

// Child.js
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { Context } from "./context";

export default () => {
  const { fakeData } = useContext(Context);

  return <div>{fakeData}</div>;
};
```

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-wilbur-xebl0?file=/src/App.js) showing the working code above in action.

I'm not entirely sure why the original method doesn't work, but I've noticed this in my own projects as well. If I find out exactly why, I'll add an edit to this post and give an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As it's mentioned in [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext):

```
const MyContext = React.createContext(defaultValue);
```

> Creates a Context object. When React renders a component that subscribes to this Context object it will read the current context value from the closest matching `Provider` above it in the tree. 
> The `defaultValue` argument **is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it** in the tree. This can be helpful for testing components in isolation without wrapping them. 
> **Note:** passing `undefined` as a Provider value does not cause consuming components to use `defaultValue`.

So, if you have rendered `Context.Provider` above the component in your component tree, you will get the value that you are passing to it as `value` prop, not the `defaultValue`.